# Oscilloscope for pants pocket

Tags: signal-processing

I am looking for an oscilloscope which:

- fits in my pants pocket (so maximum 14x8x3 cm, less preferred)
- has FFT for spectrum
- can save waveform
- has analog bandwidth 10MHz or more
- is ready to use seperately (without an USB Host)

Answer (score 2):

If it's acceptable to use a shoephone with it, the [Pokit Meter](https://pokitmeter.com/) looks handy. It and a phone (Apple iOS 10+, Android OS 5+ (Lollipop)) together would fit in your defined pocketspace, and it meets all other criteria, including an analog bandwidth of 500MHz.

Comment: For analog bandwidth:
   500mHz is very little if you mean milli with m.
   500mHz is uneraliscally much if you mean Mega with m.
   I have looked at the specs and found 1MSamples/s which would fit to 50kHz.
   For Pokit PRO I have read 600kHz.

Comment: A good smartphone scope is the [LabNation SmartScope](https://www.lab-nation.com/).